# Run vb-code for every sheet in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to tweak this code, so that it: 
 - REPLACES all images with their AlternativeText
 - Runs for all worksheets in the workbook

```
    Dim Pic As Picture
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Set Cell = Pic.TopLeftCell.Offset(, -1)
        Do
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                Cell.Value = Pic.ShapeRange.AlternativeText
                Exit Do
            Else
                Set Cell = Cell.Offset(1)
            End If
        Loop
    Next Pic
End Sub
```

Can you please think with me on this one? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all sheets in a workbook use:

```
For s = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Sheets(s).Activate

    'Enter code to be run on each worksheet here

Next s
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthew. If I try this formula, MS Excel goes to not-responding. Probably has something to do with the scope of the command as it concerns 27 sheets with +- 200 (small) images per sheets. Is there another workaround for this?